# What does an offical UDRP notification look like?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, authentication

I have a modest number of .com/.net/.org domains. They all have correct contact information on the WHOIS, but the email address gets an awful lot of rubbish sent to it. I have also been sent official looking documents through the post but those turned out to be scams.

If someone does decide to file an offical UDRP claim against one of my domains, or any other offical non-scam notifications, how would I be notified? How could I know it's real?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[UDRP](http://www.icann.org/en/dndr/udrp/uniform-rules.htm) 2(a):

> When forwarding a complaint, including
>   any annexes, electronically to the
>   Respondent, it shall be the Provider's
>   responsibility to employ reasonably
>   available means calculated to achieve
>   actual notice to Respondent. Achieving
>   actual notice, or employing the
>   following measures to do so, shall
>   discharge this responsibility:
>   (List of ways they can contact you follows)

In other words, it looks like whatever your dispute-resolution provider ([one of these fine folks](http://www.icann.org/en/dndr/udrp/approved-providers.htm)) wants it to.